# How to count unique values on pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Here's my dataset

```
Food     Day
Chiken   2
Chiken   6
Chiken   2
Beef     3
Chiken   4
Beef     6
Beef     7
```

My Output

```
Food        Day_Count
Chicken            3
Beef               3
```

`Chicken` is `3`, because it shows in day `2,4,6`
and
`Beef` is `3`, because it shows in day `3,6,7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague. I presume you want to find get unique days for each group of food?

```
df.groupBy('Food').agg(countDistinct('Day').alias('count')).show()
```

Comment: the day should be unique

Comment: See my edits. Groupby Food and count distinct days